# Haskell function to cast as a type

Tags: haskell, types

If I want a version of `reads` that returns a list of `(Int, String)`, the example I see is

```
f x = reads x :: [(Int,String)]
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to do this in point-free style (`f = g . reads`?), or if this is something you just don't/can't do in Haskell.

I haven't seen any examples of using a type as an argument, so it may not be doable.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: in Haskell we do not speak of "casting" values into a type, since there is no analogous of C casts in Haskell: e.g. if `x` is an `Int`, you can not turn it into a `Double` by adding `x :: something`. A polymorphically-typed expression such as `reads` can instead be annotated with a type to specify at which type we want to evaluate that expression. So we speak about "annotating an expression" or, sometimes, "specializing a value".

Comment: Thanks, it didn't sound right but I wasn't sure what it was called. So the question should have been phrased as "function to specialize a value" then?

Comment: Perhaps "How to specialize reads in point-free style?" would be more appropriate. Note however that this is the kind of question for which knowing how to precisely word the question is equivalent to knowing the answer. Indeed the simple specialization `reads :: String -> [(Int,String)]` is trivially point-free, so that is the answer (as Ethan Lynn shows below), hence the "point-freeness" requirement is a bit of a red-herring.

Comment: Moreover, your attempt using `g . reads` makes me believe that you are reading `reads x :: [(Int,String)]` as "evaluate `reads x` and then cast the result as `[(Int,String)]`", where casting was your `g`. It does not work that way: the type annotation is used by the compiler to point out which one of the several `reads` functions to call, namely the one producing `(Int,String)` lists. It is not an operation applied after `reads x` has been evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `f = reads :: String -> [(Int, String)]`.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic way to do what you're describing is

```
f :: String -> [(Int, String)]
f = reads
```

The benefit to doing it this way is if you have a polymorphic type the result is what you'd expect (because of the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction).

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way, but I have a suggested language extension, `SignatureSections`, which will allow you to write `f = (:: [(Int, String)]) . reads`.

Comment: Are you serious about this extension?  I'd use it.

Comment: It would be really easy to implement too, `(::a)` would just desugar to `(id :: a -> a)`.

Comment: @Dan Do you know if the compiler would be able to optimize that out as well?  Surely it has rewrite rules whenever it sees the `id` function.

Comment: @bheklilr I think the inliner would take care of that.

Comment: `flip asTypeOf (undefined :: [(Int,String)])` is not terribly long, especially if you define nicer names for `flip asTypeOf` and `undefined`. Maybe Template Haskell can also help here.

Comment: Also, with inferred holes `(id :: _ -> [(Int,String)])` would look nice.

Comment: [There's also `\x -> x :: T`](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2014/04/a-small-haskell-extension.html?m=1)

Comment: I'm totally serious.  I've implemented it in our own Haskell compiler and I've started with ghc.  It looks very easy.  The cool thing is that you can use `(:: T)` when you need a `proxy T`.

Comment: The optimizer is totally capable of getting rid of the `id` under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is actually.

```
fixIS :: [(Int,String)] -> [(Int,String)]
fixIS = id
```

I usually have a couple of functions lying around for when I want to resolve polymorphis (i.e. when I want to fix the inhibition monoid of a Netwire wire to `()`, or if I want to fix a `Num a` to `Int`). Obviously there's no point in doing this if you only need that once. The reason you might wanna do it this way is that it occasionally flows better in function definitions. Depending on how smart your haskell compiler is it might be less efficient though (in theory, the `id` could be dropped in most situations... not sure if GHC actively looks for that if `id` is given another name though).